# LinearLayout with fixed buttons width

Tags: java, android

Firsty, I've created something like that:
[BadLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETHDv.jpg)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But this layout doesn't work properly. Buttons don't have fixed width. The wider the screen is, the wider buttons are. It doesn't look good for me, because I want buttons to be perfect squares (e.g. 120dp x 120dp). I also want them to be centered. It should looks like that: [GoodLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvCRy.jpg). How to do that?

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719449/scale-imageview-to-look-the-same-on-phone-and-tablet/48719554#48719554

Comment: what is the value inside @dimen/activity_vertical_margin ?

Comment: try the answer posted which i posted if it works don't forgot to upvote

Comment: if you want to change size accordance to screen size then you have to use weight attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code to manage your view according to image you added:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: great you can like +1 , so that can help others

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer it will surely work on any sreen size without changing size of button

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:orientation="vertical"
 >
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
          <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="120dp"
             android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
             android:text="Button1"
             android:textSize="18sp"
          />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button2"
              style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
              android:layout_width="120dp"
              android:layout_height="120dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
              android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:text="Button2"
              android:textSize="18sp"
          />
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```