# app looks different on samsung devices

Tags: android

I am developing an app for Android, and every text looks way bigger in my S7 than it does in my Pixel, even if both have roughly the same density

- Pixel -> 420dpi
- S7 -> 480dpi

App looks the same on NExus6P as well, even though this one has a density of 560dpi

I have **not** increased the font size on the phone.

The end result is my layouts look very bad on S7 but perfect on my Pixel

How can I fix this? I cannot discriminate by density cause they fall into the same bucket.

[image: Pixel]
Pixel

[image: S7]
S7

As you can see the spacing is very different, on S7 it looks packed and when the score is two numbers it looks very bad

Comment: would you please share screenshots of both devices?

Comment: Can You use sdp library for Fix `Layout` ?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed done

Comment: @MohammadAli I'd rather not use any more libraries

Comment: Try to use this with margins around. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html

Comment: refer this link and in answer provide link of output ok https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719449/scale-imageview-to-look-the-same-on-phone-and-tablet/48719554#48719554

Comment: Would you please provide the XML also?

Comment: Thanks guys but this is not really answering the question of why is this looking different in these two phones