# Constraint Layout - Different set of Folders to be supported

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to Implement Login screen for my Application and finding it confusing the different screens to be supported. I want my application to work on all sets of Phones and tablets of varying screen size and density.Can someone please suggest on what all screen sizes i need to design my layouts for in Constrain Layout.

In some posts they mention to design for 
1. layout
2. layout-sw320dp
3. layout-sw480dp
4. layout-sw600dp
5. layout-sw720dp

is it enough if i design layout for above screen or do i need to add some other densities.

Comment: *I want my application to work on all sets of Phones and tablets of varying screen size and density* **.** So you have to use **sdp library** for tablet and mobile same layout. refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719449/scale-imageview-to-look-the-same-on-phone-and-tablet/48719554#48719554

Answer (score 0):

Create different layout folder for different screen size.

Try this 
https://mobikul.com/make-layout-multi-screen-resolution-android/